# estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail

Tags: javascript, firebase, dialogflow-es

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment =
    functions.https.onRequest((request, response)  =>  {
    var chat = "Here is a sample response, this should actually give you real stock information";
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.send(JSON.stringify({"speech": chat, "displayTest": chat}));
});
```

I deployed this code then when i ask a question to the agent then it should reply in the dialog response as : Here is a sample response, this should actually give you real stock information.
But it’s showing in dialog response as : not available

Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail

Can u please help me out from this.

Comment: That looks like a warning, not an error.  Is something not working the way you expect?  If so, please edit the question to explain what that is.